# jQuery/JavaScript Smooth Scrolling throughout the entire website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I came across this website http://morris-digital.co.uk/
And I love the way the scrolling website works, Really smooth and nice, I would die to have such a smooth scrolling on my website too :)

I have been searching but I can not find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

That site is accomplishing smooth scrolling with [this code](http://morris-digital.co.uk/assets/js/smoothscroll.js), which appears to be a combination of [$.smoothwheel](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel), [Paul Irish's requestAnimationFrame suggestion](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), and [this custom smooth-scrolling code](http://jsbin.com/iqafek/2/edit). (plus some custom code to patch it together).

Probably shouldn't be too hard to make something similar for your site.